# merged PDFs are showing as "in use" by WebKit when I try to delete them

Tags: pdf, itext, node-webkit

I am merging multiple PDFs into one PDF using Node, iTextSharp, and Edge. Everything is working until I try to delete the original PDFs. They are "in use" by WebKit. If I close NW they are released of course. I can run the same code but using a console app and the files can be deleted immediately. Any ideas?

```
---NW javascript--- 
var edge = require('edge');
var dotNetFunction  = edge.func({
   assemblyFile: 'E:/VisualStudio2013Projects/Edge/Edge.PDF/bin/Debug/Edge.PDF.dll',
   typeName: 'Edge.PDF.StartUp',
   methodName: 'MergePDF'
});
var payload = {
   targetPDF: 'C:/test/042715JM75-NEW.pdf',
   filesPDF: ['C:/test/042715JM75.pdf','C:/test/042715JM75-sales-copy.pdf'],
};
---C#---
namespace Edge.PDF
{
 public class StartUp
  {
   public async Task<object> MergePDF(dynamic input)
   {
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
       string lJsonData = string.Empty;
       string targetPDF = input.targetPDF;
       var filesPDF = input.filesPDF;
       using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(targetPDF, FileMode.Create))
            {
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(pdfDoc, stream);
                pdfDoc.Open();

                var files = filesPDF;                   
                foreach (string file in files)
                {               
                    pdf.AddDocument(new PdfReader(file));
                }
                if (pdfDoc != null)
                    pdfDoc.Close();
            }
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { success = true});
                });
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating an array of files (`filesPDF`), you should create an array of `PdfReader` instances. Add each of these readers to the `pdf` and after closing the `pdf`, loop over the readers once more to close them:

```
foreach (PdfReader reader in fileReaders) {               
    reader.Close();
}
```

Now the filehandlers will be released, and you'll be able to delete the files.